# TYPO3 How to create a custom "infobox"?

Tags: typo3

I am trying to make an "Infobox" with TYPO3.

In my HTML Template i have the Infobox:

```
<div id="infobox">
   <!-- ###infobox### start -->
     CONTENT from the backend
   <!-- ###infobox### start -->
</div>
...
```

Now in my Backend, i have a content element, that keeps the content for my Infobox in the Frontend:

[image: Backend]

What i want to do is: If i disable the content element via the "disable button" [image] in the backend, i want to change the CSS of my `#infobox` (**adding** `display:none`) or if I re-enable it I want to **remove** the `display:none`.

I hope I could explain my issue and hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the disabled flag of the content element to only influence the rendered output, not switch off the rendering.

I fear that this is not easily possible. The `disabled` column is part of TYPO3’s so-called *enable fields*, for which checks are added all over the place by the TYPO3 API. Due to this, "hidden" records are usually not even selected from the database, so they are also never fed to the rendering engine.

An alternative would be to use a custom content type with a custom field for your purpose, hide the "hidden" field in the form for that type and put the custom field in its place. This can all be done with standard TYPO3 core mechanisms.

What you cannot avoid however is that somebody will be able to hide/disable the content element from the page or list module. This cannot be prevented as your content needs to live in the same table (`tt_content`) as the rest of the content—and the settings for enable fields are global per table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an custom fluid content element

see: http://www.creativeworkspace.de/blog/artikel/eigene-inhaltselemente-im-typo3-cms-62x-und-7x/

or: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html

or you use a custom layout

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    layout {
        addItems {
            item1 = Name of Layout
        }
    }
}
```

after this you can get it with {data.layout} in your template

```
{f:if(contition:'{data.layout} == item1',then:'display:none')}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! But I think that isn't what i am looking for. Maybe I didn't explain my issue too good, sorry. I will EDIT my question later and go more into detail of my issue!